# Troubles with sharing values between different processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, sharing

I've different processes which waits for an event to occur (changing the state of a sensor)
I coded something like:

```
def Sensor_1():
    wait_for_change_in_status
    set counter to X
    activate_LED_process.start()

def Sensor_2():
    same function
def Sensor_3():
    same function

def LED():
    start LEDs
    while counter > 0:
        counter -= 1
        time.sleep(1)
    turn off LEDs
    active_LED_process.join()

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Sensor_1_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=Sensor_1)
    Sensor_2_process = same
    Sensor... you get it.
    activate_LED_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=LED)
```

Now I'm stuck with the exchange of the counter value. Having different processes to be able to change the counter to a specific value.
Each sensor should be able to reset the value of the counter.
The LED process should be able to "countdown the counter" and react if the counter reached zero.

What be a proper solution? I read about values, arrays, pipes and queues. 
For values and arrays I couldn't find a good documentation. Pipes seem to work only for two processes. And queues seem to not only hold one value (I'd compare a queue to a list - is this correct?)

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import multiprocessing
import sys
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
LED_time = 40  #time how long LEDs stay active (not important at this point)

def Sens_GT():
    name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print(name, 'Starting')
    while True:
        GPIO.wait_for_edge(25, GPIO.FALLING)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Open")
        LED_count = multiprocessing.value('i', 40) #For later: implementation of LED_time as a variable
        print(LED_count) #For checking if the counter is set properly
"""
Missing code:

    if "Process is already running":
        go on
    else:
        Count_proc.start()

"""
    print(name, 'Exiting') #Shouldn't happen because of the "while True:"

"""
Missing code:

def Sens_GAR():

def Sens_HT():

"""

def Count():
    name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    print(name, 'Starting')

"""
Missing code:

Import counter value

"""

    while countdown > 0:
        print(countdown)
        time.sleep(1)
        LED_count -= 1
    print(name, 'Exiting')
    GPIO.cleanup()           # clean up GPIO on normal exit
    Count_proc.join()
    sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    value_count = mutliprocessing.value('i', 0)
    lock = Lock()

    Sens_GT_proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=Sens_GT)
    Count_proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=Count)

    Sens_GT_proc.start()
    Sens_GT_proc.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value)
seems to be a good choice for your use case.
However, you don't use it the right way.

After instanciating a value with `multiprocessing.Value()`, you have to pass the object as an arguments to your sub-processes, as shown in the [multiprocessing guide](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).

So your code should be something like:

```py
def Sens_GT(counter):
    ...
    counter = 40
    ...

def Count(counter):
    ...
    while counter > 0:
        counter -= 1
        time.sleep(1)
    ...
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    value_count = mutliprocessing.value('i', 0)

    Sens_GT_proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=Sens_GT, args=(value_count,))
    Count_proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=Count, args=(value_count,))
```

For me, pipes and queues are similar mechanisms, that are very useful in multi-processing contexts.
If you can probably use them in your case, I think they are more suited for data exchange (producers, consumers) than for shared state/value between processes.